# ¿Cómo calcular y deducir el período de fechas traslapadas, mediante consulta en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Cordial saludo.

Necesito obtener un listado en el que se muestre la experiencia laboral en meses de varios profesionales, según los datos registrados en la correspondiente tabla que está asociada a la tabla de los profesionales.

Cada profesional puede tener 1 o más registros (contratos laborales) cada uno con su fecha de inicio y fecha de retiro. Pero en algunos casos, han tenido contratos cuyos períodos se traslapan ya que han laborado en dos entidades a la vez pero en diferentes horarios.

La tabla `tbl_profesionales` posee los campos con los datos generales, incluyendo, lógicamente, una llave primaria `id_profesional` autoincremental tipo `INT`.

Los campos fundamentales de la tabla `tbl_experiencia` donde se registra la exp. laboral son, entre otros:

```
id_experiencia      (INT)
id_profesional      (INT)
entidad_contrante   (VARCHAR)
ref_contrato        (VARCHAR)
cargo               (VARCHAR)                  
rol_funciones       (LONGTEXT)      
fecha_inicio        (DATETIME)
fecha_retiro        (DATETIME)
```

Ejemplo:

El profesional `A` con `id_profesional = 4319` tiene 5 contratos diferentes con las siguientes fechas:

```
id_profesional Ref. Contratante   Cargo      Fecha Inicio     Fecha Retiro

4319           C01   Empresa 1     Auditor     2010-03-15       2010-07-15

4319           C02   Empresa 2     Auditor     2010-05-10       2010-06-30

4319           C03   Empresa 1     Auditor     2010-08-10       2010-10-31

4319           C04   Empresa 1     Consultor   2010-11-01       2010-12-31

4319           C05   Empresa 3     Asesor      2010-12-15       2010-12-31
```

Para validar la experiencia en un cargo, se requiere deducir el período que se traslape en los casos que así ocurra (ver Contrato C02).

¿Cómo podría realizar esto con una consulta sql recorriendo los registros asociados a cada profesional, sin necesidad de pasarle parámetros de entrada?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Con qué consulta has intentado?

Comment: Esta pregunta es off-topic pero siento curiosidad por la palabra **traslapar** que jamás había oido, ¿qué significa?

Comment: Traslapar = solapar, sobreponer, (overlap en inglés). Traslape(s) = solapamiento, sobreposición. En el caso de fechas, ocurre cuando un período se cruza o se solapa con otro. En el ejemplo, el rango de fecha del contrato C05 se traslapa con el del contrato C04.

Comment: @Bangott gracias :) yo  usaría solapar en esos contextos, será cosa de paises y regiones

Comment: @JoséM.Carnero publiqué el código de mi consulta donde obtengo el listado de la experiencia general sin problemas. Pero no lo veo ahora. ¿Qué habré hecho mal?

Comment: Creo q falta ejemplo del resultado de la consulta final que desea, para poder ayudarle mejor. Para mi, no queda claro si lo que desea es , para cada profesional y agrupado por cargo, una fila con cada uno de los periodos "sumarizados" (esto uniendo los intervalos que se traslapen, o que incluyan completamente otros periodos en un solo periodo) o lo que desea es el calculo de la experiencia en (faltaría dererminar la unidad meses, días). Creo haberme enfrentado al mismo problema en otro motor de base de datos; pero sin una muestra de lo que desea como salida, no me atrevería a proponer

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que cada fila depende de otras filas de la misma tabla, así que para poder hacer ese cómputo, tendrías, de alguna manera, que tener, en una sola fila, varias.

La manera de solucionar tu problema sería agrupar todas las filas con rangos solapados y quedarte con el intervalo más amplio (mínima y máxima fecha de la agrupación), y ahí sumar.

La consulta para los rangos solapados sería (`tbl` es `tbl_experiencia`, `ini` es `fecha_inicio`, `fin` es `fecha_fin` e `id_profesional` es `w`, de *worker*):

```
select a.w,
       datediff(min(min(a.ini), min(b.ini)),
                max(max(a.fin), max(b.fin))) as period
tbl as a INNER JOIN tbl as b on ((a.ini < b.fin and a.fin > b.ini)
                             or (a.ini = b.ini and a.fin = b.fin))
                             and a.w = b.w
group by ((a.ini < b.fin and a.fin > b.ini)
      or (a.ini = b.ini and a.fin = b.fin))
      and a.w = b.w
```

Visto por partes:

- `INNER JOIN`: para no lidiar con `NULL`s.
- `a.ini < b.fin and a.fin > b.ini` para unir solo con otras filas que se solapen conmigo, si son del mismo trabajador (`a.w = b.w`).
- Si una fila no se solapa con ninguna otra del mismo trabajador, desaparecería de la unión debido al `INNER JOIN`, así que añadimos, por cada fila de `tbl`, una unión consigo mismo: `a.ini = b.ini and a.fin = b.fin`.
- El `group by` es exáctamente el mismo que la cláusula `on`, para que  "elimine las repeticiones que hemos creado", y así poder aplicar funciones resumen sobre el grupo creado (`min` y `max` por cada grupo).

Con esto, tenemos una fila con el intervalo de tiempo entre el mínimo y el máximo de cada rango solapado (o no), sin que rangos de diferentes trabajadores se mezclen.

Para obtener la experiencia laboral de cada trabajador:

```
select agrup.w, sum(agrup.period) as experiencia
from (consulta_anterior) as agrup
```

No lo he probado pero puede ser un enfoque para empezar a reajustar hasta que funcione.

Comment: @Peregring_Ik gracias por la sugerencia. Hice unas pruebas, pero en la cláusala GROUP BY de la consulta para los rangos solapados algo no está bien, pero no he podido dedicarle tiempo. Ya os comentaré. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Bangott Un error sintáctico o que no funciona en ejecución?

Comment: Hola trate de utilizar las sentencias en Oracle pero tengo problemas podrias ponerlas en plsql?

Comment: @JuanCarlosArce Ni idea de plsql. Investiga los errores y busca la expresión equivalente en oracle, no debería haber demasiadas diferencias.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba haciendo un join de ambas tablas.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_profesionales join tbl_experiencia on tbl_profesionales.id_profesional = tbl_experiencia.id_profesional WHERE ....
```

Con esto debería cubrir tu necesidad

Comment: Hola José Javier. Este es el código de la vista que creé para obtener la experiencia general, sin los traslapes de períodos. Lo que necesito es algo similar pero calculando los traslapes si los hubiera y deducirlos a la vez.

Comment: publiqué el código de la consulta para obtener la experiencia general, pero no lo veo. ¿Qué habré hecho mal?

Comment: @Bangott, creo  que fue editado. Lo tengo copiado, lo miro y te digo algo

Comment: Muchas gracias, @Jose Javier Segura. Hoy seguiré analizando y haciendo pruebas pues durante la madrugada me llegó una idea. Si resulta, les compartiré y ojalá no la editen :)